# how to extends te browser timeout to avoid 504 http error?

Tags: angularjs, angular, http, typescript, browser

I have a client that performing a pretty heavy request to a server, and the server succeed with the request but before it succeeded the browser got 504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT...how can I make the browser wait for the server response?

Comment: What is your backend? Nodejs, PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser will wait as long as it takes, the server is returning 504 Gateway Timeout.

Probably you have some kind of proxy between your server and browser which limits maximum wait time. Try to increase maximum execution time on proxy.